# Binary Search Program - TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary-search

I've made a simple Binary program in python from Java, At this moment I'm new in Python(Not just *new* but i've spent 20 days to learn it).

I'm getting this error:

```
Enter the number of Element: 
5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\raj\Documents\EclipseProject\PythonProject1\myProgram.py", line 15, in <module>
    print("Enter "+int(n)+" Elements")
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly
```

Here is my program:

```
array = []

print("Enter the number of Element: ")
n = input()
n = int(n)

array = [n]

print("Enter "+int(n)+" Elements")

for i in (0, n):
    array[i] += input()

print("Enter the element, you want to find:")
search = input()
search = int(search)

first = 0
first = int(first)

last = n-1
last = int(last)

middle = (first+last) / 2
middle = int(middle)

while(first <= last):
    if array(middle) < search:
        first = middle + 1
        first = int(first)

    elif array[middle] == search:
        print(int(search)+" Value found at location "+int((middle+1)))
        break

    else:
        last = middle - 1
        last = int(last)
        middle = (first+last)/2
        middle = int(middle)

if first>last:
    print(int(search)+" is NOT present in the list!")
```

As i tried in my all program to convert into *Integers*, But still i'm getting the same error.

***Help would be appreciated!!!***

Comment: `"Enter "+int(n)+" Elements"` - you are trying to concatenate string and int. Python won't do that for you, you need to explicitly cast int to str, like this: `"Enter "+str(n)+" Elements"`

Comment: Why it is needed to convert it into `str`?

Comment: Because literal `"<some text>"` is a str object. And you can't add int object to str object, you need to have both vars in same type in this case, str or int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    print("Enter "+int(n)+" Elements")
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly
```

Do you see the error? Try this:

```
    print("Enter "+str(n)+" Elements")
```

Comment: Why it is needed to convert it into `str`?

Comment: because it is `int` and needs to be `str` to be concatenated with other strings. That's what the error message tells you.